# Shopify prettier-plugin-liquid not formatting Liquid template in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to setup the plugin to allow formatting if liquid template in VScode.

Using https://github.com/shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid and
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.theme-check-vscode

[image]

Then I modified the `settings.json` (*I use VScode in Windows 11 connected to my Ubuntu Distro WSL2*)

`home > cyberquarks > .vscode-server > data > Machine > settings.json > ...`

```
{
  "shopifyLiquid.formatterDevPreview": true,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.plugins": ["prettier-plugin-liquid"]
}
```

When I do `Format Document` the Prettier plugin formats the HTML correctly but the Liquid template inside does not format the way it should be like in https://shopify.github.io/prettier-plugin-liquid/

Here's a sample document not being formatted:

Source

```
    {% assign unique_locations = "" | split: "" %}

    {% for product in site.products %}
      {% if product.category == "Dairy" %}
        {% for location in product.locations %}
          {% unless unique_locations contains location %}
            {% assign unique_locations = unique_locations | push: location %}
          {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for location in unique_locations %}
    <option value="{{ location }}">{{ location }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Actual output:

```
{% assign unique_locations = "" | split: "" %} {% for product in
site.products %} {% if product.category == "Dairy" %} {% for location
in product.locations %} {% unless unique_locations contains location %} {%
assign unique_locations = unique_locations | push: location %} {% endunless
%} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% for location in unique_locations
%}
```

Expected output:

```
{% assign unique_locations = '' | split: '' %}

{% for product in site.products %}
  {% if product.category == 'Dairy' %}
    {% for location in product.locations %}
      {% unless unique_locations contains location %}
        {% assign unique_locations = unique_locations | push: location %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for location in unique_locations %}
  <option value="{{ location }}">{{ location }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

What could be missing in my configuration?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to rename the HTML layout from `products.html` to `products.liquid` and the formatting works for liquid, but I can't rename it since it's a Jekyll layout with liquid template inside.

Comment: what does "_formatting if liquid template_" mean?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with filetype detection. I don't know anything about Prettier internals, but [this issue](https://github.com/Shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid/issues/182) looks relevant, and [this line in the code](https://github.com/Shopify/prettier-plugin-liquid/blob/main/src/index.ts#L15) is probably the first thing that would need to change.